# Slow wifi on 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04, internet

I have had 18.04 for a while but recently noticed internet browsing is either slow or there is temporarily no connection. Help with diagnostics appreciated. No problem with other Windows 10 OS on dual boot.

```
woodo@woodo-T300CHI:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for woodo: 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 59
       serial: 60:57:18:85:07:78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.16.9-041609-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=192.168.0.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:48 memory:f7000000-f7001fff
woodo@woodo-T300CHI:~$
```